# Large 16'×24' "He-Shed" Foundation Needs Fixing

Tags: concrete, construction, carpentry, architecture

I have a one year old 16×24 shed, 2×8×16 treated floor joists, 2×6 trusses, 2×4 stud walls, box soffits with vents, barn side panels, trim boards, shingled roof, gutters and downspouts, insulation, 3/drywall, electricity, windows, swinging doors. There is a concrete ramp and sidewalk. It is built on 15 deck blocks & large river gravel. So any carpenter-builder is looking back thinking huh! Yeah 15 deck blocks. This is a beautiful HE SHED and I'm worried about future problems, sinking, shifting, cracking you name it. It's heavy and I don't know if It can be lifted. Moving isn't an option.

What can I do to fix this before it becomes a "save this emergency"?

My scheme to fix is cut the floor to expose the ground, DIG, set piers, replace cut ply & recover floor with extra layer 1/2in plywood. At least 6 or 7 piers.

Any thoughts?

Would there be an easier alternative?

Comment: "I'm worried about future problems,"  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: This past is very hard to read and understand. Please reformat it and specify what your specific question is.

Comment: Also don’t shout at us in the title.

Comment: Where are you located?  *Portable sheds* are built to be lifted and the same design choices that allow them to withstand that also help minimize deflection if there is some differential settlement of your on-grade footings.  I would keep an eye on it, but as @SteveWellens said, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: How about some pictures of what you're concerned about.

Comment: Any building *can* be lifted. Sheds usually can be lifted easily/inexpensively .vs. houses or bigger things. But you appear to be borrowing trouble where nothing's actually gone wrong. It's been there a year, you don't mention any problems "actually happening now" so there's no reason (like a winter you haven't been through) to automatically expect problems going forward, or waste a large amount of effort and money on fixing those non-existent problems

Comment: What is the actual problem or is this just a theoretical concern that something might go wrong at some point in the future?